# How to avoid CSS content jumping when injecting styles when developing a Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to insert some DOM & style to my webpage.

And I don't want the process to cause any Content Layout Shift.

I tried many ways:

`document.write` - it can write the  tag but it will ruin the whole page.

`document.head.appendChild` - it says the `head` tag doesn't exist.

include external CSS - it will cause content jumping.

I just want to add some lines of CSS to the page, from my extension, into the `<head>` section so that it won't cause the content jumping. What can I do?

Comment: The simplest method is to use [content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#declaratively) with `css` key and `"run_at": "document_start"`. Alternatively you can add the DOM element to document.documentElement, no need for `head`.

Comment: `document.documentElement` works. The only way I can achieve this. inserting css failed because it will still get a blink (maybe just 1ms)